# Find classDirectory of another project in sbt

Tags: sbt

I have a project that looks something like this:

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val data = project in file("testData")

lazy val foo = (project in file("foo")).dependsOn(data % "test->test")

lazy val bar = (project in file("bar")).dependsOn(data % "test->test")
```

Some of the code needs to read the data from a file rather than as a resource on the class path.  Given these dependencies, the data jar is not automatically updated, so I need to copy the classes directory of data.  Defining a task with `IO.copyDirectory` should do that, but I need to do something like `data.classesDirectory` to know where to copy from.

I can do `data.base + target/scala-2.12/classes`, but that hard-codes several assumptions.  2.12 can be replaced with `scalaBinaryVersion`, but there are still a bunch of parts that look hacky to hard-code.

`data.settings` looks like a likely candidate, but trying to use it gives an ambiguous method warning:

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method settings in trait Project of type (ss: sbt.Def.SettingsDefinition*)sbt.Project
and  method settings in trait ProjectDefinition of type => Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]]
match expected type Any
        println("settings: " + data.settings)
                                         ^
```

`data.configurations` also looks potentially useful, but it is an empty list.

How do I do the equivalent of `show data/classDirectory` programatically?